# How to use the word extend vs put in a sentence

Tags: idioms

If you wanna say someone put their hand on my shoulder throughout the window should i say extended his hand on my shoulder?

Comment: One of many possible sentences I could construct for the scenario described is: *He **extended** his arm, **reached through** the window, and **put** his hand on my shoulder*. But that just comes down to the definition of [*extend*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extend) and what is being expressed. In this case, it's not the hand that's extended, but the arm. *He extended his hand on my shoulder* doesn't make sense. Not necessarily because of the word *extend*, but because of the overall sentence. Figuratively, you can *extend a hand* (to offer help), but not literally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of many possible sentences I could construct for the scenario described is: *He **extended** his arm, **reached through** the window, and **put** his hand on my shoulder.* But that just comes down to the definition of [extend](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extend) and what is being expressed. In this case, it's not the hand that's extended, but the arm. He *extended his hand on my shoulder* doesn't make sense. Not necessarily because of the word extend, but because of the overall sentence. Figuratively, you can *extend a hand* (to offer help), but not literally.

<sup><sup>Credit: [Jason Bassford](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/507946/how-to-use-the-word-extend-vs-put-in-a-sentence#comment1230387_507946)</sup></sup>